Cassandra join operations with spark on remote server
I am recently working on a .Net mvc project that uses cassandra as a database. I need to perform a query that requires join operation. I know cassandra does not provide joins operations by itsef but I have seen it is possible with spark.
Spark provides entegration with both cassandra and .net, but another problem is that spark and cassandra are on a remote server. I am not experienced with the spark environment, while searching I have seen spark submit and .Net for spark but I am not sure if these are what I need. My expectation is querying the remote cassandra and using spark to join query results, then obtaining the query results on the .net project. I don't know if it is possible, or it is possible with these technologies.
I am open to any kind of help and advice.
